# Android jetPack Navigation UI - Current fragment is not found in the Current Destination

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I have a Webview FragmentA . On tapping a button on the Webview, I navigate to a native FragmentB.
I am using :

```
FragmentADirections.ActionAToB action = FragmentADirections.actionAToB();
mNavController.navigate(action);
```

It does successfully navigate to FragmentB. To navigate back to FragmentA, I am using :

```
if(Objects.requireNonNull(mNavController.getCurrentBackStackEntry()).getDestination().getId() == R.id.FragmentA) {
mNavController.popBackStack(R.id.froalaFragment, false);
}
```

This doesn't work. Why is the CurrentBackStackEntry not FragmentB? Does anyone have any ideas to move forward. Appreciate all the inputs.

Comment: `mNavController.getCurrentBackStackEntry()).getDestination().getId()` basically it will return `fragmentB` right but you are comparing with `R.id.fragmentA`

Comment: It doesn't return FragmentB. That is the problem.